# Filtering dictionary of Response objects by value

Tags: python, python-requests

I have my response dictionary.

Example:

```
{10874: <Response [400]>, 11233: <Response [400]>, 13360: <Response [400]>, 15008: <Response [400]>, 11638: <Response [200]>, 14150: <Response [400]>, 15323: <Response [400]>, 14814: <Response [400]>, 12007: <Response [400]>, 11337: <Response [400]>, 13342: <Response [200]>}
```

I'm trying to create new dictionary with only response 200.

My code:

```
new_dict = {}
for k,v in results.items():
    if v == "<Response [200]>":
        new_dict[k] = v
```

But I'm not able to filter. Type of dictionary value is class 'requests.models.Response'.

Comment: can you check `type(v)`? Your dictionary doesn't look like string objects

Comment: It looks like `v` is a `Response` object, The `"<Response [200]>"` is the string representation of this object, but has nothing to do with how you acess the object. Instead, you probably need something like `v.status_code == 200`. However, the exact details depends on which library you use to create these response objeccts to begin with. You should show the code which builds the dictionary.

Comment: If the value is not a string you probably can't compare with a string. You may be looking for something like `{k: v for k, v in results.items() if v.status == 200}`  assuming all values in dictionary are scalars and not lists.

Comment: @MZ Type of dictionary value is class 'requests.models.Response'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter [*Response*](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) objects by their `status_code` attribute:

```
new_dict = {k:resp for k,resp in results.items() if resp.status_code == 200}
```